# Reference request - Outline of Edward Nelson's Inconsistency Proof

Tags: reference-request, logic, peano-axioms

Edward Nelson retracted his [inconsistency proof](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html) before it was published. Unfortunately, the [outline](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/papers/outline.pdf) given by Nelson has been removed. Is there a copy of it on the web? I am interested in how the hierarchy of sub-theories was defined. I would also accept any reference to a paper on the proof.

Comment: Who says anything changed?

Comment: There was a mistake in the argument, and he couldn't see how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read through the comments,
Terence Tao found an error
in Nelson's "proof"
and Nelson agreed that
the error was real
and invalidated the "proof".
Anyway, a version of this retracted outline is available [here](http://www.thebigquestions.com/nelson.PDF).

Comment: There were also [comments questioning the error](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/09/the_inconsistency_of_arithmeti.html#c039598).